# Chat window hiding behind Twenty Eleven header

Tags: css, theme-twenty-eleven

I use [the Chat plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/chat/), but I found a bug when using it with the Twenty Eleven theme in WordPress 3.2. If you scroll, the chat window goes behind the header image.

[image: Screenshot with chat window behind header image]

I used this plugin with no problems up to WordPress 3.1.4, and it works find in 3.2 - except for this problem. I guess the `z-index` is the reason, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: Let me know the reason for negative vote?

Comment: Please downgrade your version to WP 3.1.4 to solve this issue. Next to that you need to do a bug-report if you think it's a bug: http://codex.wordpress.org/Reporting_Bugs (I can't tell you why your question was downvoted, wasn't me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a `z-index` problem. The `#branding` element has a `z-index` of 2, in other themes (like Twenty Ten, the default in 3.0 and 3.1), it was not set.

A simple solution is to set the `z-index` of `#chat-block-site` to something higher.

```
#chat-block-site
{
    z-index: 10;
}
```